# What's the difference that make class or def in django

Tags: django, class, function

I read the django book, and some points confused me .

One is that when we creat form.py or models.py, we write class inside, but there's def that make the view showing on website happen in view.py.

So what's the difference? what if i define some classes in my view.py, can i use them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use them. It is recommended, that you use the structure that Django has created though - makes it easier for other coders to understand.

I  think you should also read through some basic python tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Class Based Views but they are quite newer concepts.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/

I personally think functions are easier to write and django itself within its code base uses functions a lot more than class based views.

Answer (score 0):

The Models represent the database. Each Model is a database table. An object of the Model class is just a row in the DB. So everytime you instantiate an object of the Model class, you are actualy creating an entry for your table (i.e. a row). Therefore, it makes sense to represent the Model with a class. Representing with functions will make no sense at all.

Views can be represented with both functions and classes:

**1. Functions**

A request to a URL is handled by a function view. It takes the request, process the data and outputs the result through a template.  This is the simplest way out of 2 to implement your views, as a beginner. Practice an understand this one first.

**2. Class Based Views**

Views can also be represented as [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/). Read the docs and find out that they were created because, sometimes, the functional views always follow a same pattern. CBV were introduced to make life easier while respecting the DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. Nevertheless, these are a little bit harder to understand at first sight. I recommend you to start learning them after you have understood the functional views.

**[EDIT]**

Sorry, I told you about `Models` instead of `Forms`. But this is the same reason. Forms are represented as a class because you are instantiating an entry for that form